# Connect Strato4 to ESP32 using UART

Tags: esp32, uart, arduino-esp32

I have a Strato4 as a GPS Tracker and I want to connect it to an ESP32 using the UART-Interface with which both devices are equipt. However the Strato4 does not seem to send any information towards the ESP.

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

HardwareSerial mySerial(1); // Use UART 1
const int RXD2 = 16;        // Example GPIO pin for RX
const int TXD2 = 17;        // Example GPIO pin for TX

void setup() {
  // Initialize the default serial (UART0) with a baud rate
  Serial.begin(9600); // Use a baud rate like 9600
  Serial.println("New Run");

  // Initialize UART1 on the specified RX and TX pins
  mySerial.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);
}

void loop() {
  if (mySerial.available()) {
    String data = mySerial.readString(); // Read incoming data
    Serial.println("Received data: " + data); // Print data to the console
  } else {
    Serial.println("No data available");
  }
}
```

I tried running this code on the ESP, but mySerial does not seem to be availible, as I get "No data available" as my output.

Comment: Have you tried switching TX/RX pins around? Tx-->Rx and Rx-->Tx